# Why I can't connect to localhost (nodejs)?

Tags: node.js

```
const http = require('http')
const port = 3000

const server = http.createServer(function(req,res){

    res.write('hello')
    res.end
    
})


server.listen(port, function(error) {
    
    if(error){
        console.log("Something went wrong", error)
    }

    else{
        console.log(`Server is listening on ${port}`)
    }
})
```

I get Server is listening message on terminal but can't connect to the localhost on browsers do you know what is wrong?

Comment: how are you connecting to the localhost ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a typo, but you aren't calling `res.end`, you're just referencing the method (and doing nothing with it). Add parenthesis to actually call it, and you should be OK:

```
res.end()
// Here^
```

Comment: Thank you so much I literally deleted one of the projects that I started because of this.